# Event overriding RactiveJS

Tags: ractivejs

I find myself in a little bit of trouble because triggering an event on a element will also fire the event binded to its parent element like the following.

```js
var template = new Ractive({
  el: 'wrapper',
  template: '<div on-click="open">OPEN<div on-click="close">CLOSE</div></div>'
});

template.on({
  open: function(e) {
    alert('opening');
  },
  close: function() {
    alert('closing');
  }
});
```

```css
div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can stop a DOM event bubbling by calling its `stopPropagation` method. The `event` argument passed to Ractive event handlers stores the original DOM event as `event.original` - so you can do it like so:

```js
var template = new Ractive({
  el: 'wrapper',
  template: '<div on-click="open">OPEN<div on-click="close">CLOSE</div></div>'
});

template.on({
  open: function(e) {
    alert('opening');
  },
  close: function(e) {
    alert('closing');
    e.original.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

```css
div > div {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 50px;
  cursor: pointer
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.ractivejs.org/latest/ractive.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: You can also `return false;` from the handler and Ractive will call `.stopPropagation()` (and `.preventFefault()`) for you.